# Typo3 is Not working on Web server

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

**Warning:**    `require_once(D:/wamp/www/sevenstar_caters/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Package/PackageManager.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home4/code9/public_html/sevenstarcaterers.com/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Core/ClassLoader.php on line 184`

```
Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'D:/wamp/www/sevenstar_caters/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Package/PackageManager.php' (include_path='/home4/code9/public_html/sevenstarcaterers.com/typo3/contrib/pear/:.:/opt/php53/lib/php') in /home4/code9/public_html/sevenstarcaterers.com/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Core/ClassLoader.php on line 184
```

Web page Link http://www.sevenstarcaterers.com/

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have moved from a unix mashine to a windows mashine without clearing the cache. Remove all files from `typo3temp` and visit the install tool at `http://www.sevenstarcaterers.com/typo3/install`. Check out the `Important actions` to clear the cache and `Folder structure` to fix the folder permission/creation in typo3temp.